# Excel Column Chart Data in table but not in graph

Tags: excel, graph

I am currently creating a column chart that compares two years of sales data (2012 and 2013). I want to show the data in a table below the column graph that also includes a percentage change. I have this all figured out, but cannot seem to figure out a way to eliminate the percentage change column from the graph itself.

So my question is how can I keep the % change data in the chart below the graph but eliminate it from the column graph itself??

Thank you.
Patrick Wilson

Answer (score 4):

If it's in the table it's in the chart. A few work arounds:

1. Make the series fill for % bars no fill and same for the outline
2. Plot it on a second axis and format such that this axis is not displayed
3. Fake the table, using cells and don't use the data table. Format and position the chart above it.

In my experience the 3rd one is the most work, but the best. Chart tables are hard to format.

Answer (score 0):

I change the chart type (ie. bar chart) and the switch back to the pie chart and it worked. Hope it works for others. Scott

Answer (score 0):

For a bar chart, I change the chart to a combo, make the data I don't want shown a line and then format it so that there is no fill or border, and delete the legend and select "Data Table with Legend Keys" No color will show next to the row of data not visible on the on the chart.